# unicode-math doesn't print \mathit{\alpha}

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode-math, italic, tex-gyre-math

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%%% The culprit lines start
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
%%% The culprit lines end.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\someColor}{blue}
%%%% \myMacro should print the argument in italics.  If the argument is moreover some nontrivial text (producing more than just a single symbol), it should be set up as text (with proper spacing and ligatures).
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myMacro}{m}{
  \ifdefempty{\someColor}{\ifmmode\mathit{#1}\else\textit{#1}\fi}{\ifmmode\mathit{\color{\someColor}#1}\else\textit{\textcolor{\someColor}{#1}}\fi}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}\noindent
\(\myMacro{a}\)\\
\(\myMacro{alpha}\)\\
\(\myMacro{\alpha}\)\\
\(\myMacro{Finite\_word\_with\_\alpha}\)\\
\myMacro{a}\\
\myMacro{alpha}\\
\myMacro{\(\alpha\)}\\
\myMacro{Finite\_word\_with\_\(\alpha\)}
\end{document}
```

to `xelatex` results in

[image: output with unicode-math and new fonts]

As you see, `\mathit{\alpha}` won't print as given (but will print if the culprit lines pertaining to unicode-math are removed).  Why?  How to get italicized `\alpha` regardless of whether it's a standalone symbol or part of an italicized math identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference in how `unicode-math` treats Greek letters in math mode compared to legacy TeX.

In legacy TeX, `\alpha` is an “invariable” symbol in the sense that it is unaffected by math alphabets. With `unicode-math` it is. In your case, `\alpha` should be taken from the text italic font, which doesn't have a glyph for it and you get

```
Missing character: There is no  in font TeX Gyre Termes Italic/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!
```

Using `\symit` is out of the question: it will print `\alpha`, but treat letters as math symbols, with no ligature and spaced out.

You can replace the Greek letters with `\symit{<letter>}` when in math, with `\(<letter>\)` when in text.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newcommand{\someColor}{blue}

%%%% \myMacro should print the argument in italics.
%%%% If the argument is moreover some nontrivial text, 
%%%% it should be set up as text (with proper spacing and ligatures).
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myMacro}{m}
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnTF { ! \tl_if_exist_p:N \someColor } { \tl_if_blank_p:V \someColor }
   {
    \justaman_mymacro:nn { } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \justaman_mymacro:nn { \color{\someColor} } { #1 }
   }
 }

\regex_const:Nn \c_justaman_mymacro_greek_regex
 {% one or more Greek letters; fill up
  ([\c{alpha}\c{beta}\c{gamma}]+)
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \justaman_mymacro:nn
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF
   {% math mode, fix the Greek letters
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_all:NnN
     \c_justaman_mymacro_greek_regex % search
     { \c{symit}\cB\{\1\cE\} } % replace
     \l_tmpa_tl % token list to massage
    \mathit{#1\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
   }
   {% text mode, don't bother and issue error if Greek is present
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_all:NnN
     \c_justaman_mymacro_greek_regex % search
     { \c{(}\1\c{)} } % replace
     \l_tmpa_tl % token list to massage
    \textit{#1\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\myMacro{a} \(\myMacro{a}\)

\myMacro{\alpha} \(\myMacro{\alpha}\)

\myMacro{Finite\_word\_with\_\alpha\beta}
\(\myMacro{Finite\_word\_with\_\alpha\beta}\)

\end{document}
```

Fill up the regex constant with the Greek letters you expect to be found in such constructions.

I'm not sure about the dual definition for text and math mode: in my opinion there should be *never* (hardly ever) a command that works in both modes. Anyway, I left it; if you want to make it work also with Greek letters, the adjustment should be easy… `;-)`

[image]

A version only for math mode where you are even freed from the burden of typing `\_` for underscores.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newcommand{\someColor}{blue}

%%%% \myMacro should print the argument in italics.
%%%% If the argument is moreover some nontrivial text, 
%%%% it should be set up as text (with proper spacing and ligatures).
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myMacro}{m}
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnTF { ! \tl_if_exist_p:N \someColor } { \tl_if_empty_p:N \someColor }
   {
    \justaman_mymacro:nn { } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \justaman_mymacro:nn { \color{\someColor} } { #1 }
   }
 }

\regex_const:Nn \c_justaman_mymacro_greek_regex
 {% one or more Greek letters; fill up
  (\c{alpha|beta|gamma}+)
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \justaman_mymacro:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:NnN
   \c_justaman_mymacro_greek_regex % search
   { \c{symit}\cB\{\1\cE\} } % replace
   \l_tmpa_tl % token list to massage
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { _ } { \c{_} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \mathit{#1\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\(\myMacro{a}\)

\(\myMacro{\alpha}\)

\(\myMacro{Finite_word_with_\alpha\beta}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Just_A_Man You mean the first version, do you?

Comment: @Just_A_Man In the first version, there is no provision for math, when `\myMacro` is called in text mode. Why should it support math in text?

Comment: @Just_A_Man I made the requested changes. Color is only applied in math mode.

Comment: @Just_A_Man Color has been reinstated. I stay with my opinion: you should always use this in math mode. It is a math variable.

Comment: @Just_A_Man “Sequence ” is exactly the same thing in both cases. When I say “The vector *v* is orthogonal to *u*” I use math mode, because they're math objects. Your case is exactly the same.

Comment: @Just_A_Man That's just an example. Don't look too deeply into it. Anyway, it's a further example that `\myMacro` should only be used in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

By default (and different to the behavior of `amsmath`), `unicode-math` uses text font in the argument of command `\mathit`. you can find the following error info in log

```
Missing character: There is no  in font [lmroman10-italic]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

Here `lmroman10-italic` represents a variant of the current text font Latin Modern.

`unicode-math` provides a series of configuration options to make `\mathxx` commands use math font, see the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf), sec. 4.4.2, Table 4. In your case, you can use

```
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX, mathit=sym]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
```

Answer (score 1):

\alpha is U+1D6FC), \mathit uses a text font and doesn't have this glyph and if you look in the log you can find a missing char message:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6FC) in font TeXGyreTermes/I:mode=base;
```

You can use `\symit` instead. But personnally I think that you have no math here and should use text mode instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=0.88]
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}
Text: \textit{Finite\_word\_with\_α}

Math: \(\symit{Finite\_word\_with\_\alpha}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd *exclude* `\symit` for this application: try `\symit{difference}`.

Comment: @egreg yes I too. Imho this is text. And even with the example, the `Finite` looks odd.

Answer (score 0):

The `unicode-math` package uses `\mathit`, `\mathrm`, and so on for words in math mode, and `\symit`, `\symrm` and so on for math symbols.  So, if you use `\mathit{ft}`, you might get different kerning than `\symit{ft}`, or even a text ligature.  This is very evident when you have two consecutive *f* symbols in math mode and no italic correction:

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a character is missing!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\mathit{f f l \alpha} \\
\symit{f f l \alpha}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

The `\tracinglostchars=2` command will give you the error message:

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+1D6FC) in font [lmroman10-italic]:+tlig;!
```

Which will tell you that LaTeX is searching for a mathematical italic lowercase *α* in the text italic font, not the math font.  Without `\tracinglostchars=2`, the warning will be buried in the `.log` file.

If you don’t want to change every `\mathit` in your text to `\mathnormal` or `\symit`, you can change this default behavior and load the package with

```
\usepackage[mathit=sym]{unicode-math}
```

With this change, the same MWE compiles to:

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

There are similar options for `mathrm` and several others (see [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf#9)), but if you define `mathrm=sym`, you should also `\setoperatorfont` to fix commands such as `\sin` and `\log`.

It is also possible to change the font used for `\mathit`.  It’s the `ItalicFont=` of `\setmathrm`, like `\mathbfup` is the `BoldFont=` of `\setmathrm`.  In the unlikely case that you want to typeset a Greek word in math mode using `\mathit` and not `\textit` or `\operatorname`, you could do it as follows:

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if a character is missing!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\pagestyle{empty}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[Scale = 1.0] % Supports Greek.
\setmathrm{CMU Sans Serif} % Set to the main text font by default.
\setoperatorfont\mathit

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\textit{γωνία} \\
\mathit{γωνία} \\
\operatorname{γωνία}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern Unicode sample]